# how to use this without subquery. I need to use with join to get same result set

Tags: sql-server

How to use this below query as join instead of subquery. It's resulting poor performance

```
    SELECT EBIJ.* FROM BUDLINEITEMS EBIJ
WHERE ReferenceId NOT IN (SELECT ImportKeyId FROM External_Blk_Itm_JounalEntries)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT EBIJ.* 
 FROM BUDLINEITEMS EBIJ
 LEFT JOIN External_Blk_Itm_JounalEntries E
 ON EBIJ.ReferenceId = E.ImportKeyId
 WHERE E.ImportKeyId IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT EBIJ.* FROM BUDLINEITEMS EBIJ
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM External_Blk_Itm_JounalEntries E
                  WHERE EBIJ.ReferenceId = E.ImportKeyId )
```